# If the listen socket is non-blocking socket, accept returns non-blocking socket?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

On any platforms,
does the option of socket returned by `accept()` function depend on  the option of the listening socket?

For example,
I wonder if the listen socket is in non-blocking mode, does `accept()` return a non-blocking socket?

Comment: The accepted socket is in blocking mode, but every other attribute is inherited from the listening socket, including for example the receive buffer size. This is critically important for setting window scaling: the receive buffer size has to be set on the listening socket, as by the time the accepted socket is accepted it is too late for window scaling to come into effect if the size is > 64K.

Answer (score 2):

I won't say there doesn't exist any platform where the blocking-mode of the returned TCP socket varies with the blocking-mode of the accept-socket, because I haven't used all platforms; but I will say that I've never seen that behavior on any of the platforms I develop for (MacOS/X, Windows, Linux, BSD, etc).  AFAIK the sockets returned by `accept()` always have the default settings for a new TCP socket, which includes that the socket is in blocking-mode.  That said, the [accept man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) page doesn't seem to explicitly address the question one way or the other.

In any case, if you're worried about it, the safe thing to do is manually set (or unset) blocking-mode on the socket returned by `accept()`, so that you can guarantee it's in the state you want.

Comment: So, you mean accept returns socket in default mode Right? it was very helpful for me thank u so much

Comment: The accepted socket is in blocking mode, but every other attribute is inherited from the listening socket, including for example the receive buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned today that within FreeRTOS+TCP's socket implementation, child sockets inherit the listen socket's settings, including the Receive timeout, which is effectively a proxy for blocking.